# Avoid escaping of double quotes

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

I have some commands I want to execute in a bash script.
Now when we use single quotes the variable is taken literal and not the value.
So doing e.g. `ls "$SOME_DIR"` is not the same as `ls '$SOME_DIR'`
How can we handle a mix of quotes and double quotes in a way that not everything is cluttered by escaping double quotes?
E.g. how to valid something like:

```
ssh server.com "mkdir \"/foo/bar/"$final"\""
```

How can I avoid all these escapes since the longer the commands it becomes unreadable and very easy to break?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my solution. It was much easier than I thought initially! :)

Comment: If possible, use a script. Or make the directory tree locally and `rsync` or `tar c . | ssh tar x x -C /`.

Answer (score 3):

After much playing around with `heredocs` and `herestrings`, it seems that the simplest solution would be this:

```
ssh server.com "mkdir '/foo/bar/$final'"
```

Yes, `bash` will do variable substitution of `$final` despite the single quotes, just like it would in `echo "test'$final'"`.

Note: as pointed out by @muru, this will not work if `$final` contains a single quote.

Comment: To be honest that does not seem much of an improvement to me. I was hoping there was a way to avoid all the clutter from quotes

Comment: Yeah that's true... You could do it using a heredoc, but I find it even less readable. I edited my answer to include that possibility.

Comment: `"...'$var'"` working fine depends on the contents of `"$final"`. What if contained single quotes?

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's the only case where it wouldn't work...

Comment: The statement "bash will do variable substitution of $final despite the single quotes" sounds confusing. In fact it won't. What happens in this case, single quoted part of the command is being send to remote shell where it has no single quotes when arrived, thus  $final gets expanded by *remote* shell. Single quotes protects the variable from *local* shell expanding.

Comment: Nope, I think that's not how it works. In this case, the single quotes don't protect from anything, because they appear inside double quotes. Try it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Opposite quoting, (*i.e.* single quotes in double quotes, and *vice versa*), can substitute for escapes.  Without using escapes or *here documents*, consider how to use `echo` to display this text:

> He didn't look back, and said "It can't be helped."

Surrounding it with either double or single quotes won't work.  Alternating opposite quotes do work:

```
echo "He didn't look back, and said "'"It can'"'t be helped."'"'
```

Output:

```
He didn't look back, and said "It can't be helped."
```

Unfortunately, the above `echo` is just as difficult to read as escapes would be.

The happy medium is to use opposite quotes and escapes both as needed to reduce the visual monotony:

```
echo "He didn't look back, and said \"It can't be helped.\""
```

---

Applied to the code:

```
ssh server.com 'mkdir "'"/foo/bar/$final"\"
```

This should work even if `$final` contains a `'`.

Unrolling the quote, we have:

1. `'mkdir "'`, which preserves a space and an opening double quote.
2. `"/foo/bar/$final"` which returns contents of `$final` prior to launching `ssh`.
3. `\"` closing double quote, preserving dirname for `ssh`

Comment: I don't understand how this works or how I would properly apply this

Answer (score 0):

I think the real need pretty much depends on where/when you want the variables to be expanded - before sending the commands, locally or after sending, remotely. Both cases are valid.
Either way, if your command fits in one line, I'd suggest you using `<<<` redirection surrounding command with either double or single quote respectively

**1. Resolving variables before sending command**

```
final="defined_locally"; ssh server.com <<<"final="defined_remotely" ;mkdir /foo/bar/"$final" "
```

**2. Resolving variables after sending command**

```
final="defined_locally"; ssh server.com <<<'final="defined_remotely"; mkdir /foo/bar/"$final" '
```

First one  will create

> /foo/bar/defined_locally

and the second one will create

> /foo/bar/defined_remotely

directory on the remote server

As you see there's no need in escaping in both cases untill you want to mix local and remote defined vars in one command.

**UPD:**

`<<<`

strictly speaking is not a redirection, but [HERE-STRING](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)

UPD2:

Thanks to @Rastapopoulos for pointing to the

`Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`
messages that accompanies the command execution

Although it does no harm

Comment: What is the `<<<`?

Comment: I've extended my answer with the reference to the document page

Comment: You would still need to call `sh` though, no?

Comment: No explicit calls for sh requried, the remote command is executed by the default user's shell there.

Comment: Hmm, but what's your command in this case: `<<< ...`? I tried in my terminal and it does produce different results.

Comment: <<<'ALL_INSIDE_THESE_SINGLE_QUOTES_IS_MY_COMMAND'  or 
<<<"ALL_INSIDE_THESE_DOUBLE_QUOTES_IS_MY_COMMAND". 
You may consider <<<LEFTMOSTQUOTE and RIGHTMOSTQOTE as delimteters allowing you to specify a command inside without taking care of escaping.

Comment: Still not convinced. Have you tried running the command without `sh`? On my computer `ssh localhost <<< "echo test"` produces `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Comment: Yes, i tried that before giving my answer. What you are getiing is 
 echo-specific message as echo requries terminal
you may satisfy it with ssh -t key
You wouldn't have had that message for  mkdir command.

Comment: Well, I do in fact... Three more points: 1) what are the final `" "` for in your first line of code? 2) I think the first command does not work if `$final` contains spaces, does it? 3) It seems that the behaviour of the first line would be the same without `<<<`, would it not? Thanks anyway!

Comment: 1) the last one is the trailing part of `<<<"  "` construction
the second but last is the closing quite of `"$final"`
2) it does, but not the expected way =). To take take care about spaces one should quote the whole path "/foo/bar/$final". But that has nothing to do with escaping/noescaping

Comment: Are you sure about your explanation of the behaviour of `<<<`? Because with my version of bash `cat <<< "hello """  world"` does not work. Sorry to bother you, but I want to understand properly. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67178/discussion-between-tagwint-and-rastapopoulos).

Answer (score 0):

Is this a job for the `printf` builtin?

```
ldo@theon:~> f='He didn'\''t look back, and said "It can'\''t be helped."'
ldo@theon:~> echo "$f"
He didn't look back, and said "It can't be helped."
ldo@theon:~> ssh hypatia echo "$f"
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
ldo@theon:~> ssh hypatia echo $(printf %q "$f")
He didn't look back, and said "It can't be helped."
```